# how to use lldb sbapi in xcode

Tags: lldb

```
`lldb::SBDebugger::Initialize();
lldb::SBListener sbListener;
lldb::SBTarget sbTarget;
lldb::SBError sbError;

sbTarget.ConnectRemote(sbListener, "connect://127.0.0.1:3333", nullptr, sbError);
if (sbError.IsValid()) {
    printf("%s\n", sbError.GetCString());
    //got an error   "SBTarget is invalid"
}`
```

xcode 11.6  connect ios13.3.1 got an error   "SBTarget is invalid"
how to use lldb sbapi in xcode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a supported use of lldb within Xcode.

Xcode knows nothing about new debuggers you make by hand, and since Xcode is the one that hooks debuggers up to the Console window, it wouldn't know to provide you a way to interact with them.

Also, lldb is an event-driven framework, but your new target is hooked up to an event listener that Xcode knows nothing about, so it won't know the drive its event loop.

Even if you did manage to get one of the debuggers in Xcode to wait for your new target's events, Xcode expects one target per debugger, so if you caused events for a second target to show up, Xcode would just get confused.

I think what you really want to do is to customize the startup sequence (essentially script the action of the Run part of Xcode's Build & Run button). That is a perfectly reasonable enhancement request.  If you are so motivated, feel free to file a bug report.  These days it looks like you use the Feedback Assistant app for that purpose.  See:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

But I don't think you are going to have much luck doing this without cooperation from Xcode.

Comment: Note, there are plenty of other ways you can use the SB API's in Xcode.  You can add Python-based commands to enhance your command-line experience.  You can add Python based breakpoint callbacks, Frame Recognizers, etc.  What you can't do is make a whole new debug session behind Xcode's back.